# how to detach list of pytorch tensors to array

Tags: python, list, numpy, pytorch, tensor

There is a list of PyTorch's Tensors and I want to convert it to array but it raised with error:

> 'list' object has no attribute 'cpu'

How can I convert it to array?

```
import torch
result = []
for i in range(3):
    x = torch.randn((3, 4, 5))
    result.append(x)
a = result.cpu().detach().numpy()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stack them and convert to NumPy array:

```py
import torch
result = [torch.randn((3, 4, 5)) for i in range(3)]
a = torch.stack(result).cpu().detach().numpy()
```

In this case, `a` will have the following shape: `[3, 3, 4, 5]`.

If you want to concatenate them in a `[3*3, 4, 5]` array, then:

```py
a = torch.cat(result).cpu().detach().numpy()
```